# Get week using date data and do some calculation in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My data is something like this:

```
(201601030637,2,64.001213)    
(201601030756,3,63.5869656667)   
(201601040220,2,62.758471)
```

which the first column is year (2016) month (01) day (03) hour (06) and minutes (37) connected to each other.

I want to sum the values of third column based on the week. How can I group them to have 52 different groups for entire year? Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ToDate` to convert your datestring to datetime type. Then use `GetWeek` to get weeknumber. Finally use `GROUP` to group by weeknum and `SUM`.

```
A = LOAD '/path_to_data/data' USING PigStorage(',') as (c1: chararray, c2: int, c3: float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE GetWeek(ToDate(c1,'yyyyMMddHHmm')) as weeknum, c1, c2, c3;
C = FOREACH (GROUP B BY weeknum) GENERATE group as weeknum, SUM(B.c2) as c2_sum;

DUMP C;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetWeek](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#get-week) and create a new column from the first column.Then group by the new column and use [SUM](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#sum).Assuming you have loaded the data to a relation A.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE A.$0,A.$1,A.$2,GetWeek(A.$0) as week_of_year;
C = GROUP B BY (B.$4);
D = FOREACH C GENERATE group,SUM(B.$2);
DUMP D;
```